# Spring security configuration - addFilterBefore is not working for PUT, PATCH and DELETE

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have prepared configuration for `Spring security` for `API` calls. It should verify `JWT` token provided in the request.

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/v2/api/**/*").authenticated().and()
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

and my controller method

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    @PutMapping(value = "/v2/api/dashboard/projects")
    public List<Projects> getProjects(Principal principal) {
        return dashboardService.getProjects();
    }
```

and by executing request I get

> Resolved
>   [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
>   Request method 'PUT' not supported]

When I change it to `GetMapping` request is being handled properly.

After settings logs from `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` I can see that `PUT` not supported is not returned from `/v2/api/dashboard/projects` but from '/forbidden' which for obvious reasons doesn't support such methods.

Further investigation with debuging `jwtRequestFilter` showed that filter is not even executed on `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` methods.

code of it:

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtRequestFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtTokenUtil;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String requestTokenHeader = "";
        try{
            requestTokenHeader = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "token").getValue();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex ){}
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.contains(".")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader;
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                log.error("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                log.error("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not look like token");
        }
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to make it works so `PUT` and `PATCH` methods would be filtered with given class?

Comment: What is your request's body when you `PUT`?

Comment: Can you show the class where `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    @PutMapping(value = "/v2/api/dashboard/projects")
    public List<Projects> getProjects(Principal principal) {
        return dashboardService.getProjects();
    }` resides?